# ASP:Button always redirects to site homepage

Tags: c#, asp.net

EDIT: Added all of the ASPX code on this page.

I have an asp:Button that does not call the function specified and instead redirects the user to the site homepage. I can understand the page crashing if the function specified in onclikc didn;t match a function name in the code behind file but redirecting to the homepage makes no sense to me. I don't call a redirect to the homepage anywhere on this page either.

the aspx code

```
<asp:Panel ID="Error_Panel" runat="server" visible="false">
<p>An error has occured on this page use the back button in your browser or home button below to return to the home page. Please click button below for techncial details on this error.</p>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="DetailsButton" runat="server" Text="Details" onclick="DetailsButton_Clicked"/>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="TechnicalDetails" Visible="false" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="HideTechDetails_Button" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Hide" onclick="HideTechnicalDetails" />
<asp:Button ID="Home_Button" runat="server" onclick="returnHome" Text="Home" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Backend function written in C#...for now it just redirects to my stackoverflow profile.

```
protected void DetailsButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Response.Redirect("http://stackoverflow.com/users/1464160/derek-drummond");
   }
```

Comment: Are you redirecting to your homepage somehow? can you post more code?

Comment: I don't call a redirect to the homepage anywhere on the site. I'm not sure what other code would be needed, nothing else uses this button or  function.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that it might be some simple issue, can you post your aspx?

Comment: What happens if you put the actual intended URL in a browser? Does it mysteriously go to the home page too?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The actual intent is to swap the visibility of two panels not redirect to a different page. I put the redirect in there for testing purposes.

Comment: Have you tried a minimal `Error_Panel.Visible = false; OtherPanel.Visible = true;` (or similar) in the click handler?

Comment: Thats originally what I tried. When I discovered it wasn't working I removed the other panel and the two lines of code swapping the vulnerability. When all that is back in place it still just redirects to the homepage.

Comment: Have you got the entire markup? Bizarrely I have had a similar issue when I have had an image control with an image incorrectly specified (or not at all)  I never got into the internals I just corrected the image.